# MKMapView is freezeing UI in iOS 8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, ios8.4

When zoom in or zoom out the mapview it freeze user interface. I have noticed that viewForAnnotation delegate method execute continuously. This happens only in iOS 8.4. iOS 9 it is working smooth.
Can anyone have idea what's causing issue?

Comment: issue has been fixed. I save value to user default inside viewForAnnotation method. May be in ios 8 it takes time to store data into user defaults. I remove that particular line of code and its work smooth.

Comment: I found this issue by using profiler "Time Profile" template. Time profile template shows how much time particular line of code takes to execute.